# Что лучше использовать и как?

Tags: html, css, github, psd

Что использовать margin или padding, и каким образом?
Верстка на bootstrap
[image: tajem]

Comment: Настораживает вопрос "каким образом". Использовать margin в целом понятней (на мой взгляд) т.к. позволяет перемещать контент в правильном "русле" и без проблем. В вашем случае кажется что на первый блок у вас margin: 20px 0 20px 0 или около того. А второй - margin-top:20px. Но т.к. в bootsrap вроде все на паддингах построено то мб и паддингами такого же добиться можно.

Answer (score 0):

Padding. потому что будет удобнее делать отступы сверху и снизу

Comment: Margin способен делать абсолютно тоже самое. С небольшим нюансом - вертикальный маржин "схлопывается" если идет друг за другом. Т.е. если элементы друг под другом, то padding 1px создаст 1px для одного элемента и для другого. И в итогде 2px между блоками.А вот margin 1px даст 1px между блоками. Ссылка - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189452/when-to-use-margin-vs-padding-in-css